# Change color of ipywidget color upon click (active)

Tags: python, css, ipywidgets

I have the following button, in which I would like to turn green when clicked:

```
   see_button = widgets.Button(
        description='Click me',
        disabled=False,
        button_style='', # 'primary', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
        style=dict(font_style='italic',
                    button_color='DarkGray',description_width= '200px'),
        center = 'right'
        )
display(see_button)
```

[image]

There is no option to under button_style or button color to change upon clicking. Also you like it to turn back to grey if unclicked or another button is clicked.